# Checking if Datetime is in between a given Datetime interval

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I have a table which looks like this:
[image]

What I am trying to do is to sum up a few values within a given datetime range. Let's say for example between 01.01.2016 00:30 and 01.01.2016 02:00.

My if clause looks like this.

```
If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Samariter" And .Cells(i, 1).Value >= "01.01.2016 00:30:00" And .Cells(i, 1).Value <= "01.01.2016 02:00:00" Then
```

And if I run the algorithm, it runs correctly, BUT:

If I try, for example, the range from 25.1.2016 20:00 until 26.1.2016 02:00:

[image]

This is my if clause again:

```
If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Samariter" And .Cells(i, 1).Value >= "25.01.2016 20:00:00" And .Cells(i, 1).Value <= "26.01.2016 02:00:00" Then
```

If I run this, it will start at the correct line, but will exceed the upper bound of the datetime interval.

What is the problem here?

Comment: what do you mean with `will exceed the upper bound of the datetime interval`? You mean that the values of image, according to VBA, are higher than 26.01.2016 02:00:00?

Comment: yes exactly! the algorithm adds values (of the columns to the right) which are not within the given datetime range.

Comment: How are your cells in Column A formatted? I believe your issue lies within the comparison >= & <=, Is VBA assuming that they are strings? You could use `DateDiff()` to do a date/time calculation and then check whether they are before or after your given choice...

Comment: The values in column A are defined as "custom". Sounds like a good approach, I will definitely try it out.

Comment: Have you tried to make those custom values normal dates in VBA? Something like `Cdate(.Cells(i, 1).Value`

Comment: Could you add debug.print in your code in order to see what dates are selected when above if is true?

Comment: I guess your custom format is `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm` right?

Answer (score 0):

Xabier's answer solved the problem, the if-clause should look like this in order for the algorithm to run properly:

```
If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Samariter" And DateDiff("s", .Cells(i, 1).Value, "25.01.2016 00:00:00") < 0 And DateDiff("s", .Cells(i, 1).Value, "31.01.2016 23:59:59") >= 0 Then
```

Comment: Please look at the difference between .Value and .Value2 this would compare date serials and not strings http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=315:excel-vba-dates-a-time-format-function-user-defined-date-number-a-string-formats&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? The datetime values are custom and I have defined them as: TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm

Comment: I was thinking what would happen if you would take instead of .Cells(i,1).Value something like .Cells(i,1).Value2. I expect that you would get a number which is date serial - these numbers can be directely compared. However, it seems that you would like to have some hardcoded dates in the code :)