# Checking if a date falls in a given interval not working

Tags: excel, date, vba

I want to check if a given date, in the format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss falls within a given interval. The interval is defined by the start date, with the same format, and its duration in decimal (so half an hour would be 0.5 hours), as in the example below

Example of the intervals in the sheet called filter
[image]

Example of the data in the sheet called data
[image]
I have written the following code:

```
Sub filter_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastDataRow, LastDataCol, LastFilterRow, LastFilterCol, FilterStart, FilterDuration, 
_FilterEnd As Long 
' get boundaries
With Sheets("data")
    LastDataRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastDataCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
With Sheets("filter")
    LastFilterRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastFilterCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

'filter the data
lineFilter = 2
For rowFilter = 2 To LastFilterRow
    FilterStart = Sheets("filter").Cells(lineFilter, 5).Value
    FilterDuration = Sheets("filter").Cells(lineFilter, 6).Value
    FilterEnd = FilterStart + FilterDuration / 24
    For colData = 1 To LastDataCol
        rowdestination = 2
        colDestination = colData
        If colData Mod 2 <> 0 Then
            For rowData = 2 To LastDataRow
                dataDate = Sheets("data").Cells(rowData, colData)
                If dataDate >= FilterStart And dataDate <= FilterEnd Then
                    Sheets("data").Cells(rowData, colData).Copy
                    Sheets("filtered data").Cells(rowdestination, colDestination).PasteSpecial
                    Sheets("data").Cells(rowData, colData + 1).Copy
                    Sheets("filtered data").Cells(rowdestination, colDestination + 1).PasteSpecial
                    rowdestination = rowdestination + 1
                End If
            Next rowData
        End If
    Next colData
Next rowFilter
Sheets("data").Range("A1:ZZ1").Copy
Sheets("filtered data").Range("A1:ZZ1").PasteSpecial
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now I expect the date in C12 to be within the interval defined in E3 and F3, but the macro doesn't copy them.

This is not the case.

Comment: dataDate doesn't appear to have been Dim'd (also colData) so you probably have type conversion issues. You should look to cast the dates into CDate types for comparison. If you add 'Option Explicit' to the top of your code you will be able to find undimensioned variables

Comment: @Tragamor, shouldn't I get an error in such case? Because I don't get any.

Comment: I would advise using DateDiff to check difference between dates and base my condition on that. Please see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811340/checking-if-datetime-is-in-between-a-given-datetime-interval/48811906#comment84628013_48811906

Comment: Not necessarily; dates are a difficult beast to work with in VBA as regional settings aren't taken into account while they are within worksheet formulas. The dates may be being parsed incorrectly which will affect comparisons: are your dates the 3rd July or 7th March?

Comment: For displaying dates I can recommend always to use the [format `YYYY-MM-DD` according to ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which is the only format with only one interpretation. This makes it also much easier to parse a string into a date in VBA.

Comment: If you're unable to change the date format, similar to what @Pᴇʜ has suggested, I would recommend splitting the data for comparison, such that left(cell,2)=month(rng) & right(left(cell,10),4)=year(rng), to make exact comparisons, not relying on the listed date format.  You can do this check in a logic if-statement, e.g., if year_cell = year_rng AND (month_cell = month_rng OR day_cell = day_rng) then...

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, sadly I have no voice in setting the format of the data. I get them from a database

Comment: @Tragamor, the dates are 7th March, and I have already changed to regional settings to handle that.

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle, if you could put your comment in an answer I'd gladly upvote it

Comment: @L. Dutch Ok. I posted more elaborate answer with some additional references. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that issue lays in line `If dataDate >= FilterStart And dataDate <= FilterEnd` comparing date-time data type directly, using comparison operators may return unexpected results. I would advise using VBA's `DateDiff` function ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datediff-function)). Similar issue was encountered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811340/checking-if-datetime-is-in-between-a-given-datetime-interval) thread and was successfully resolved using `DateDiff` function.